# Do Python equal types have different values ever?

Tags: python, integer, floating-point, type-conversion, language-lawyer

In Python, if I have the following code:

```
r = Numeric(str)
i = int(r)
if r == i :
    return i
return r
```

Is this equivalent to:

```
r = Numeric(str)
return r
```

Or do the == values of different types r and i give different return values r and i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends if the class implements an adequate `__eq__` method to override `==` operator.

Edit: Added a little example:

```
>>> class foo:
...     def __init__(self,x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __eq__(self,y):
...         return int(self.x)==int(y)
... 
>>> f = foo(5)
>>> f == '5'
True
>>> 5 == '5'
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets see:

```
>>> float(2) == int(2)
True
```

Different types can be considered equal using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "do the == values of different types r and i give different return values r and i?"

Answer: clearly they are different; they have different types.

```
>>> print(type(i))
<type 'int'>
>>> print(type(n))
<class '__main__.Numeric'>
```

In the above example, I declared a class called `Numeric` to have something to test.  If you actually have a module that implements a class called Numeric, it won't say `__main__.Numeric` but something else.

If the class implements a `__eq__()` method function, then the results of `==` will depend on what that function does.

```
class AlwaysEqual(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

With the above, we can now do:

```
>>> x = AlwaysEqual(42)
>>> print(x == 6*9)
True
>>> print(x == "The answer to life, the universe, and everything")
True
```